# Wi-Fi problems on CM11 (4.4 KitKat, Samsung Galaxy S3)

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I've recently encrypted my Samsung Galaxy S3 (with CyanogenMod 11-20141115-SNAPSHOT-M12-i9300 installed) using `vdc enablecrypto wipe`, and since then I've been having a problem with the Wi-Fi radio on that phone. When I try to connect to my Wi-Fi network, this error message gets saved in the system log:

```
INFO/wpa_supplicant(7306): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=[CENSORED] status_code=1
```

It does connect when I'm really close to the router though. However, as soon as the signal drops past -40 dB, the phone can no longer reach hosts outside of my local network, although it stays connected to the Wi-Fi network itself.

Despite all that, mobile data (HSPA+) works flawlessly. Could anyone help me with the Wi-Fi though?

EDIT: I tried performing a full wipe in my TWRP recovery and reinstalling CyanogenMod, but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was caused by a corrupted installation of the Xposed Framework - the issue got solved as soon as I reinstalled it.